Creating new attributes based on content of another attribute
I am trying to adapt the following JSON with jolt
[
  {
    "id": "abc",
    "colour": "black | orange | anthracite",
    "material": "polyester | aluminium | v2a | steel",
    "temp min": "45 °C",
    "temp max": "-35 °C",
    "category": "rope",
    "length": "18 m"
  },
  {
    "id": "def",
    "colour": "black | orange | anthracite",
    "material": "polyester | aluminium | v2a | steel",
    "temp min": "45 °C",
    "temp max": "-35 °C",
    "category": "various"
  },
  {
    "id": "ghi",
    "colour": "black | orange | anthracite",
    "material": "polyester | aluminium | v2a | steel",
    "temp min": "45 °C",
    "temp max": "-35 °C",
    "categorie": "rope",
    "length": "10 m"
  }
]

The JSON needs to be transformed as follows.
The featureName has to be added as attribute,
as well as the featureUnit (if Unit is available).
That means every time the featureValue ends on
a certain list of specified units "°C, m, cm, mm, Years"
a Unit attribute has to be created and the unit has to be removed from the original value
[
  {
    "id": "abc",
    "featureName_colour": "colour",
    "featureValue_colour": "black | orange | anthracite",
    "featureName_material": "material",
    "featureValue_material": "polyester | aluminium | v2a | steel",
    "featureName_temp min": "temp min",
    "featureValue_temp min": "45",
    "featureUnit_temp min": "°C",
    "featureName_temp max": "temp max",
    "featureValue_temp max": "-35",
    "featureUnit_temp max": "°C",
    "featureName_category": "category",
    "featureValue_category": "rope",
    "featureName_length": "length",
    "featureValue_length": "18",
    "featureUnit_length": "m"
  },
  {
    "id": "def",
    "featureName_colour": "colour",
    "featureValue_colour": "black | orange | anthracite",
    "featureName_material": "material",
    "featureValue_material": "polyester | aluminium | v2a | steel",
    "featureValue_temp min": "45",
    "featureUnit_temp min": "°C",
    "featureName_temp max": "temp max",
    "featureValue_temp max": "-35",
    "featureUnit_temp max": "°C",
    "featureName_category": "category",
    "featureValue_category": "various"
  },
  {
    "id": "ghi",
    "featureName_colour": "colour",
    "featureValue_colour": "black | orange | anthracite",
    "featureName_material": "material",
    "featureValue_material": "polyester | aluminium | v2a | steel",
    "featureValue_temp min": "45",
    "featureUnit_temp min": "°C",
    "featureName_temp max": "temp max",
    "featureValue_temp max": "-35",
    "featureUnit_temp max": "°C",
    "featureName_categorie": "categorie",
    "featureValue_categorie": "rope",
    "featureName_length": "length",
    "featureValue_length": "10",
    "featureUnit_length": "m"
  }
]

I managed to solve the featureName Problem with the following spec:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id": "[&1].&",
        "*": {
          "$": "[&2].featureName_&",
          "@": "[&2].featureValue_&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

But I have no idea how to solve the featureUnit-Problem.

Hi do we know the names of attributes that needs to be added as Units? Or it will be varying every time with input.

Thank you for your Message..Unfortunately the namens of the Attributes are Not fix. They vary with Input.

Assuming the whole value patterns are the same as with the presented input, then consider the following spec to distinguish the value sets :
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id": "[&1].&",
        "*": {
          "*|* * *": {//values with multiple spaces or the else case
            "$1": "[&3].featureName_&2",
            "@1": "[&3].featureValue_&2"
          },
          "* *": {//values with single space
            "$(0,1)": "[&3].featureValue_&2",
            "$(0,2)": "[&3].featureUnit_&2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]


Thank you so much Barbaros. Unfortunately the values do not always corresond to the pattern presented in my example.
Nevertheless your approach inspired me, so that I finally found the solution.

In addition to the help provided by Barbaros, this spec does the job as well. It is alittle bit clumsy, I know :)
   [
  {
    // First shift operation to structure the input data based on "id"
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        // Move the "id" field to the outer level, preserving its current value
        "id": "[&1].&",
        "*": {
          // For each key, create a new field combining featureName with its parent key
          "$": "[&2].&1.featureName_&1",
          // Temporarily store the feature values in TEMP fields
          "@": ["[&2].&1.featureValueTEMP0", "[&2].&1.featureValueTEMP1", "[&2].&1.featureValueTEMP2"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // Modify operation to split the temporary values into lists of words
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          // Split the values in TEMP1 and TEMP2 by spaces
          "featureValueTEMP1": "=split(' ',@(1,&))",
          "featureValueTEMP2": "=split(' ',@(1,&))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // Modify operation to extract specific elements from the list
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          // Extract the last element from TEMP1
          "featureValueTEMP1": "=lastElement(@(0))",
          // Extract the first element from TEMP2
          "featureValueTEMP2": "=firstElement(@(0))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // Second shift operation to map feature values and units correctly
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        // Keep the "id" field at its place
        "id": "[&1].&",
        "*": {
          "*": "[&2].&1.&",
          // Handle cases where TEMP1 contains a unit like "m" or "°C"
          "featureValueTEMP1": {
            "m|°C": {
              // If the value is "m" or "°C", store the unit in featureUnit_&3
              "@1": "[&4].&3.featureUnit_&3",
              // Map the TEMP2 value into featureValue_&3
              "@(2,featureValueTEMP2)": "[&4].&3.featureValue_&3"
            },
            // Otherwise, use TEMP0 as the value
            "*": {
              "@(2,featureValueTEMP0)": "[&4].&3.featureValue_&3"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // Remove the temporary fields that are no longer needed
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "featureValueTEMP0": "",
          "featureValueTEMP2": ""
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // Final shift operation to simplify the remaining structure
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id": "[&1].&",
        "*": {
          "*": "[&2].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
